# MVVM Execute method every x seconds/minutes with on window countdown

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, timer

I'm making a WPF Application using MVVM. 
This application has a function that needs to execute every minute. And on the View, it needs to show a countdown until it´s executing this method.

How would i do that?

Answer (score -1):

Initial answer deleted due to bad practice.
You should build a periodic Task like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2016/06/30/asynchronous-infinite-loops-instead-of-timers/)

Comment: It doesnt seem to restart